# Camera plugin doesn't work in ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to use camera plugins and file upload in ionic for take a photo. But, when I click the button, it doesn't work. I look at the console, there's no error.

View :

```
<button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="takePhoto">Take Photo</button>
<button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="choosePhoto">Choose Photo</button>
<img ng-src="{{user.picture}}">
```

app :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.controller('MainController', ['Camera', function($scope, Camera){
    $scope.getPicture = function(options){
        var options = {
            quality : 75,
            targetWidth : 200,
            targetHeight : 200,
            sourceType : 0
        };

        Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData){
            $scope.picture = imageData;
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    };

    $scope.takePicture = function(options){
        var options = {
            quality : 75,
            targetWidth: 200,
            targetHeight: 200,
            sourceType: 1
        };
        Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData){
            $scope.picture = imageData;
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}])

.factory('Camera', function($q){
        return {
          getPicture: function(options) {
             var q = $q.defer();

             navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
                q.resolve(result);
             }, function(err) {
                q.reject(err);
             }, options);

             return q.promise;
          }
       }
    })
```

All help is appreciated.
I'm newbie.

Answer (score 0):

First Install the Camera plugin using the following command,

```
 cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

Then, try to implement the following code to take photo from camera,

**HTML File,**

```
 <ion-content>
    <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="takePhoto">Take Photo</button>
    <img ng-src="{{ImagePath}}" style="width:250px;height:250x;"/><br/>
 <ion-content>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.takePhoto = function() {
       navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI)
       {
          $scope.ImagePath = imageURI;
       }, function(err) {
          // Ruh-roh, something bad happened
       },{quality: 50,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          targetWidth: 300,
          targetHeight: 300
       });
    }
})
```

Hope this will Help you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the $cordovaCamera in your factory as well as you are also not using all the imageOptions, please see the official Documentation of ngCordova Camera Plugin. [Here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/)

```
<button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="takePictures">Take Photo</button>
```

please use proper ng-click function to bind with the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following simple controller to see if it works . Also dont forget to install Cordovacamera plugin. I dont see your code using any cordova plugin

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {
 $scope.takeImage = function() {
        var options = {
            quality: 80,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 250,
            targetHeight: 250,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.srcImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function(err) {
            // error
        });
    }
});
```

Use following code into your index.html

```
<ion-content ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <img ng-src="{{srcImage || 'img/dummy.jpg'}}" id="srcImage" width="250 " 
             height="250" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;"/><br/>
        <button class="button button-full button-positive " ng-click="takeImage() ">Take Image</button><br/>
    </ion-content>
```